# Getting selected members from multiselect list view ctrl

Tags: c++, mfc, controls

I have a list view control which at the moment only allows one item to be selected. I then read this via the following code:

void CApp::OnNMClickList1(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{ 
    int nSelected = (m_List.GetSelectionMark());
...

However, now I want to make this list able to multiselect, GetSelectionMark() always returns one index. Can anyone help me recode this to return a list of selected indexes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`GetFirstSelectedItemPosition()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxt1akf(VS.80).aspx) to find first selected item, then [`GetNextSelectedItem()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1dasx7t(VS.80).aspx) for the rest and you're done. :)

Comment: Just saw those on the MSDN, if anyone is interested, I will post the full bit of code.

Comment: is there any way to find the really first selected position in the order it was slected..? like click and drag from 'fifth to first item' in the list, how can I get 5 as the first selected item. (as it was selected first)